# Create a local wifi network connected to shared wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

We have recently moved to a shared office space where they have a shared internal wifi network.

We would like to have our own "local" wifi network where we can control simple firewall rules for our connected devices. The problem is that there are no ethernet connections available, only wifi.

Is there a way to setup a wifi router that provides us with our own network but connects us to internet via the existing internal shared wifi network?

We have no access to do any configurations on the existing shared wifi.

Comment: Can you implement your own network with your own ISP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use a travel router, that has repeater mode. They are used for traveling and you have to connect to public Wi-Fi and want to be protected. For example [GL iNet](https://www.gl-inet.com/) has travel routers that run on [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/) and also includes OpenVPN, WireGuard for VPN Encryption. Anyway if you google a little you can find videos going over all the features. There is one on amazon for as little as $30. You can try it out and see if this is something that will work for you. If it does you can get a higher end one.

Comment: I picked up a travel router and it was exactly what I needed. Awesome little thing!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure you can do this with a *single* device. However, you can get something called a wireless bridge (e.g. [Linksys](https://www.linksys.com/ca/support-article/?articleNum=140882)) which will connect to a WiFi network and provide a wired Ethernet connection to that network. You can then connect that cable to your own router/firewall/AP to provide your private network.

If you want to guarantee privacy, you can use a VPN (virtual private network) to tunnel through the outer network to a VPN service somewhere out in the Internet.

Comment: I have been looking at access points that can act in "client mode" to do exactly this. Just seemed like a complicated solution but maybe it's the only way. Thanks